# Changing the origin of a Geotiff and resampling

Tags: gdal, interpolation

I have georeferenced data from 1 to 10M resolution in GeoTiff format.  I can use gdal to resample everything to 5M, but I would like to store the data so that rather than having an origin at a decimal value, it would have a 1s digit of 0 or 5.

So rather than having an origin of:

(607474.537941714515910,4373727.438771144486964)

It would be:

(607475.0, 4373725.0)

with an interpolation option offered (I used bilinear for the resampling to 5M.)

Comment: Can you explain where the interpolation part enters in the question? Or do you just want to set the final raster extent to decimals ending in 0 or 5? Also, how did you convert the georeferenced points into raster? It probably would be in that step you could set your raster's extents. Also, resampling from a lower resolution (10m) to a higher resolution (5m) is usually not a best practice, because you would be "inventing" data.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, couldn't you just take the extent, round it to the next round integer and then subset the original raster to the new extent? Of course you would lose some data on the edge of the raster, but that would be necessary.

Comment: I don't think so...if the data points were 
(3.5, 7.5) -- then the next data point south is (3.5,2.5) -- but I want to interpolate so I have (5,5) followed by (5, 0)

Comment: Ok, so if you have a point (3.5, 7.5), you subtract the mod 5 of each value. 

3.5 mod 5 = 3.5, 3.5 - 3.5 = 0, 
7.5 mod 5 = 2.5, 7.5 - 2.5 = 5, 

So your point would be (0,5)

Comment: But that doesn't involve any interpolation.  It's just assigning the elevation of a pixel to a different point. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: I wouldn't assign the elevation of a pixel to a different point. What I was suggesting is clipping the raster to the extent that you want. I'm not quite sure what you mean by interpolation. In order to interpolate a value, you would need to know the elevation values on either side of the missing data. If you are trying to fill in missing data at the edge of the raster, you would need to extrapolate, which would be almost like guessing. Depending on how you are using the data, I can't imagine extrapolation would be ideal.